# Swift/Xcode - Is it possible to control HTML elements on a webpage?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I was wondering if it would be possible to control HTML elements on a web-page from an iOS app. So for example, I display [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) using a `UIWebView`.

I then wish to achieve the following, if this idea/concept is possible:

- Detect whether the user has entered anything in the search-bar
- If the user has, automatically search without the user needing to press
  any button

I understand this would be quite tricky, but would it be possible to do so?

Comment: I'm sure you could intercept the html, scrape it for the search box, and toss in some clever javascript (i.e. modify the page).  That would be very fragile though, and break if the underlying HTML page ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject JavaScript as a possibility.

uiWebView.evaluateJavaScript("JavaScript here", completionHandler: nil)

OR

_ = wkWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "JavaScript here")